# Add Span and class to PHP array

Tags: php, wordpress

The Wordpress plugin I am using calls the invoice due date using the php:

```
<p><?php wpi_invoice_due_date2(); ?></p>
```

this then displays as one column

```
<p>Due Date: 10 May 2019</p>
```

I am looking to keep this in line with the rest of the template and to do this, I need to add a style to the date but am unsure how to achieve this.

I have created an override to the plugin to allow me to style things.

As you will see below, I have added a '' to the Due Date text. however, this is not consistent with the rest of the page, and what makes it more difficult is that this row and the rows above are all wrapped in the same  element.

I could probably ammend the  to make things work, however, I am keen to find out if there is a work around for this.

```
if ( !function_exists('wpi_invoice_due_date') ) {
function wpi_invoice_due_date2( $args = "" ) {
  global $invoice;

  $defaults = array(
      'return' => false,
      'text'   => __('<span class="duebold">Due Date:</span> ', ud_get_wp_invoice()->domain),
      'format' => 'd F Y'
  );

  extract( wp_parse_args($args, $defaults) );

  if ( empty( $invoice['due_date_year'] )
       || empty( $invoice['due_date_month'] )
       || empty( $invoice['due_date_day'] ) )  return;

  if ( !$return ) {
    echo $text.date($format, strtotime( $invoice['due_date_day'].'-'.$invoice['due_date_month'].'-'.$invoice['due_date_year'] ));
    return;
  }

  return $text.date($format, strtotime( $invoice['due_date_day'].'-'.$invoice['due_date_month'].'-'.$invoice['due_date_year'] ));
}
```

I have added the span in this line:

```
'text'   => __('<span class="duebold">Due Date:</span> ', ud_get_wp_invoice()->domain),
```

However, it is what comes after Due date that I would like to change

Currently I have

Invoice Number: **1111111**

Invoice Amount: **£120.00**

**Due Date:** 01 March 2019

Ideally, I would like

Invoice Number: **1111111**

Invoice Amount: **£120.00**

Due Date: **01 March 2019**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<span>` tag from the text, and add it around the date using `sprintf`:

```
if ( !function_exists('wpi_invoice_due_date') ) {
function wpi_invoice_due_date2( $args = "" ) {
  global $invoice;

  $defaults = array(
      'return' => false,
      'text'   => __('Due Date: ', ud_get_wp_invoice()->domain),
      'format' => 'd F Y'
  );

  extract( wp_parse_args($args, $defaults) );

  if ( empty( $invoice['due_date_year'] )
       || empty( $invoice['due_date_month'] )
       || empty( $invoice['due_date_day'] ) )  return;

  $text.= sprintf(
    "<span class='duebold'>%s</span>",
    date($format, strtotime( $invoice['due_date_day'].'-'.$invoice['due_date_month'].'-'.$invoice['due_date_year'] )));

  if ( !$return ) {
    echo $text;
    return;
  }

  return $text;
}
```

[sprintf Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

## Personal note:

Please, never pass HTML to the `__()` function, you can always find a way to insert the HTML tags inside the string and use `__()` to only retrieve the needed text. HTML inside text strings makes translating them harder and prone to errors. If you don't need translations, just use plain text.